# JQueryUI DatePicker Widget and Picker on (same) page

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

Technically, they are not on the "same" page - the widget is on the main page, and the picker is on a sub-page which gets loaded inline through Jquery ajax.

I have a Datepicker in Widget mode on a page which shows up fine

```
<div id="datepicker" style="margin-top: 3px;"></div>
```

JQuery portion -

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
       var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
       if ($.inArray(y + '-' + (m + 1) + '-' + d, highlightDates) != -1) {
           return [true, 'ui-datepicker-testavailable', ''];
       }
       return [true];
    },
    onSelect: function (selectedDate, instance) {
       PopulateScheduledTestsByDate(new Date(selectedDate));
    },
    onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
       GetScheduledTestDatesByMonth(month, year);
  }
});
```

This works fine and shows up beautifully on the page.

There is a section on this page, which loads up a second page using Jquery Ajax. On this "second" page, there is a datepicker attached to a textbox, which does not show up when clicked on the text box.

```
<input id="runSchedule" name="runSchedule" data-bind="value: runSchedule, visible: pageModeEdit" class="inputfield" style="display: none" />
```

JQuery portion -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#runSchedule').datepicker();
});
```

If I comment out the Widget datepicker Javascript on the main page, the input datepicker shows up fine. But I cannot get both to show up together. Anything I am missing here?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/V4Zgm/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've added more details to the question now. Technically the two controls are not really on the 'same' page - the sub page (picker page) gets loaded asynchronously from the main page (widget page).